# OSRM avoid routes with ferry

Tags: lua, routes, openstreetmap, osrm

I'm running a local OSRM-backend, and trying to customize the profiles in order to avoid the routes with ferries, but I don't know very well what parameters should I overwirte.

I've added 'ferry' to this, in `profiles/car.lua`:

```
 avoid = Set {
  'area',
  -- 'toll',    -- uncomment this to avoid tolls
  'reversible',
  'impassable',
  'hov_lanes',
  'steps', 'ferry',
  'construction',
  'proposed'
},
```

And to this:

```
   access_tag_blacklist = Set {
  'no',
  'agricultural',
  'forestry',
  'emergency',
  'psv',
  'customers',
  'private',
  'delivery',
   'ferry',
  'destination'
},

-- tags disallow access to in combination with highway=service
service_access_tag_blacklist = Set {
    'private'
},

restricted_access_tag_list = Set {
  'private',
  'delivery',
  'destination',
  'customers','ferry'
},
```

But after re run all the server with `osrm-extract --profile profiles/car.lua data/export.osm` I'm getting same results

Any idea on what could be doing wrong, or something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `ferry` to the access tag list won't work since `ferry` is neither a valid key nor a valid value for [`access`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:access). Instead, ferry is a specific type of [route](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:route).

I'm not familiar with OSRM profiles. However [profiles/car.lua](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/profiles/car.lua) contains a speed for ferry routes:

```
route_speeds = {
  ferry = 5,
  shuttle_train = 10
},
```

Try setting it to a very large value. This even has the advantage that OSRM *will* take the ferry route if it is the only option for reaching the destination.